# Looking for birth records in what was Oppeln, Germany?

Tags: germany, 20th-century, birth-records

My mother's parents' names were Wawrzysniec and Anna Klak.

Their children were born between 1923 and 1941.

I am unable to locate any birth record for their children from Grudschütz (Gruden 1939-1945), Oppeln, Germany (Grudzice, Opole, Poland now). Can you help?

Comment: Hi Deanna, welcome. I have edited your post to remove information about potentially living people (those born within the last 100 years). I think your question is still answerable without those details, so hopefully someone with expertise in this area will be along shortly to help.

Comment: Part of the problem is the 100-year privacy restrictions on the records. The other is access to the original records (not online) in the Polish archives, if they survived WW2.

Comment: Thank you for that information.  I have located her parents graves and have photos unbelievably! @bgwiehle

Comment: Deanna, how were you able to locate images of the graves? I am also trying to find some from my ancestors in Opelln.